# Devise user model ignoring model validations on email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

My Devise user model is ignoring the uniqueness check I placed on the model,

```
validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 }, uniqueness: true
```

And is instead hitting the database and blowing up when it hits the unique constraint on the database,

> Duplicate entry 'test@test.com' for key 'index_users_on_email'

Any ideas how I make it respect the model level validation?

Comment: Seems that without additional context it's hard to guess if this is issue with Devise or you bypass validations somehow.

Comment: Not sure how I would be bypassing validations. At least I am not doing it explicitly.

Comment: You can try adding `!` at the end of `save` or `update_attributes!(...)` where the user instance is saved and see if that throws any exception. Adding `!` will throw exception and terminate process while not adding will just return `false` value.

Comment: There is a bunch of ActiveRecord methods which skips validations. http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#skipping-validations Fallen tests would be the greatest context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly have no idea what happened here, but I just tried it again and it worked, with 2 errors for the email addresses,

> Email has already been taken

I then removed my explicit uniqueness check, and it that reduced it down to 1 error. So Devise must handle the unique check automatically and something must have been gotten screwed up with my local server. Devise also handles the presence check automatically as well.

Side note, you do however need to put an explicit validator on the email length, otherwise it blows up.

```
 validates_length_of :email, maximum: 255
```